# Patch Value to Angular text box without using FormControls and NgModel

Tags: angular, textbox, angular11

I am New to Angular I need to patch value to text box without using `FormControls` and `NgModel` while page loading

Here is my code

```
calendar;

 <input type="date" (change)="customCalanderStartDateHandler($event)"  >



customCalanderStartDateHandler(event) {

    const option = event.target.value;

    const convertDate = new Date(option);
   
    this.calendar = convertDate;
  }
```

I seek your help to solve this problem . If i need to add any attribute or field or something else  please let me Know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try binding value attribute

```
//.html
<input type="text" value={{datePatcher}} (change)="customCalanderStartDateHandler($event)"/>

//.ts
public datePatcher ="2/11/1999";
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [viewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#viewchild) Decorator with Angular [Date](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#datepipe) Pipe

component html File(.html)

```
<input #dateControl type="date" (change)="customCalanderStartDateHandler($event)"  >
```

component typescript File(.ts)

```
@ViewChild('dateControl') input: ElementRef;
datePipe = new DatePipe('en-US');

customCalanderStartDateHandler(event) {
 const controlValue = event.target.value;
 const todayDate = this.datePipe.transform(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
 this.input.nativeElement.value = todayDate;
 console.log(this.input.nativeElement.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not change value of input directly because Angular keeps DOM object and "View" in sync.

So, use Renderer2 to update it correctly.

```html
<input #dateInput type="date" (change)="customCalanderStartDateHandler($event)"  >
```

```js
@ViewChild('dateInput') input: ElementRef;


constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}


customCalanderStartDateHandler(event) {
    const convertDate = this.getConvertedDate() // Get date
    this.renderer.setValue(this.input.nativeElement, convertDate)
}
```

Check this post here about using Renderer2 https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/renderer2-angular/